# Search a string in java by wild card search like approach

Tags: java

Given that M_16x16_a_b_c can contain any number in place of a, b, and c: I wonder what could be the best way to use wild card search approach so that I can search for any of the possible strings by doing something like 'searchfor("M_16x16_*_*_*")'.

Comment: Would regex work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use regular expressions for this.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) is a good tutorial on them.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are good a general purpose solution.

For your particular example you could try the following, which might give better performance.

```
String s; // Assign somewhere
boolean hit = s.startsWith("M_16x16_")
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
// URL that generated this code:
// http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=M_16x16_111_222_333&-13&-42&-15&-26&-14&-16&-27&-43&2&-44&3&-45&4&-5&-6 

import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="M_16x16_111_222_333";

    String re1="(M)";   // Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 1
    String re2="(_)";   // Any Single Character 1
    String re3="(16)";  // Integer Number 1
    String re4="(1)";   // Any Single Digit 1
    String re5="(6)";   // Any Single Digit 2
    String re6="(x16)"; // Alphanum 1
    String re7="(1)";   // Any Single Digit 3
    String re8="(6)";   // Any Single Digit 4
    String re9="(_)";   // Any Single Character 2
    String re10="(\\d+)";   // Integer Number 2
    String re11="(_)";  // Any Single Character 3
    String re12="(\\d+)";   // Integer Number 3
    String re13="(_)";  // Any Single Character 4
    String re14="(\\d+)";   // Integer Number 4

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13+re14,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String w1=m.group(1);
        String c1=m.group(2);
        String int1=m.group(3);
        String d1=m.group(4);
        String d2=m.group(5);
        String alphanum1=m.group(6);
        String d3=m.group(7);
        String d4=m.group(8);
        String c2=m.group(9);
        String int2=m.group(10);
        String c3=m.group(11);
        String int3=m.group(12);
        String c4=m.group(13);
        String int4=m.group(14);
        System.out.print("("+w1.toString()+")"+"("+c1.toString()+")"+"("+int1.toString()+")"+"("+d1.toString()+")"+"("+d2.toString()+")"+"("+alphanum1.toString()+")"+"("+d3.toString()+")"+"("+d4.toString()+")"+"("+c2.toString()+")"+"("+int2.toString()+")"+"("+c3.toString()+")"+"("+int3.toString()+")"+"("+c4.toString()+")"+"("+int4.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}

//-----
// This code is for use with Sun's Java VM - see http://java.sun.com/ for downloads. 
//
// Paste the code into a new java application or a file called 'Main.java'
//
// Compile and run in Unix using:
// # javac Main.java 
// # java Main 
//
```